# assist me to understand behind the scenes of title.compareTo(a.title()); codeInside

Tags: java, string, sorting, collections, compareto

```
//Sorting userDefined object from ArrayList<>...    

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Song implements Comparable<Song>{
    String title;
    String movie;
    String rating;

    public int compareTo(Song s){
        //System.out.println(getTitle()+"   "+s.getTitle());
        /*The upper comment is for testing purpose, 
         *because i wanted to see whats the value getTitle() compares..
         *but i couldn't understand.
         */
        return getTitle().compareTo(s.getTitle());
    }

    public Song(String t, String m, String r){
    //R.I.P. Naming Convention.
        title = t;
        movie = m;
        rating = r;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return title;
    }
}

class ArrayListDemo{
    ArrayList<Song> songsList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ArrayListDemo();
    }

    public ArrayListDemo(){
        getSongs();
        System.out.println(songsList); 
        Collections.sort(songsList);   
        System.out.println(songsList);
    }

    public void getSongs(){
        try{
            File file = new File("SongsList.txt");
            //check below for SongsList.txt 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                addSong(line);
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addSong(String lineToParse){
        String[] token = lineToParse.split("/");
        Song nextSong = new Song(token[0], token[1], token[2]); 
        songsList.add(nextSong);
    }
}

SongsList.txt
Soch Na Sake / Airlift / 9.1
Jeena / Badlapur / 8.7
Tere Sang Yaara / Rustom / 8.8
Aayat Ki Tarah / BaajiravMastaani / 7.9
Ikk Kudi / UdtaPunjab / 7.5
Tay Hai / Rustom / 7.8

Output:-
Before Sorting...
[Soch Na Sake , Jeena , Tere Sang Yaara , Aayat Ki Tarah , Ikk Kudi , Tay Hai ]

After Sorting...
[Aayat Ki Tarah , Ikk Kudi , Jeena , Soch Na Sake , Tay Hai , Tere Sang Yaara ]
```

Caution:- Beginner Level English Ahead!!!

So this is working of my program... Reference :-HeadFirstJava 2nd , JukeBox3 Page no.- 550

So, coming to the problem..

i understood most of them...but this is where my mind is rolling.. o.O

```
public int compareTo(Song s){
    return getTitle().compareTo(s.getTitle());
}
```

**getTitle() & s.getTitle()**

from where getTitle() gets value and compares it...
ok, i know that compareTo() compares String but and i also know the -1,0,1 (<,=,>) rule,
the thing which cracking me up is from where getTitle() gets the value.
and one more thing... the book says that

**Collections.sort(songsList);**

when this method gets called, the sort method sends an element from songsList to compareTo() method.. means s.getTitle() = title of the element sent bye sort(). Right ?

but from where the first getTitle() gets the value... the one which is after the return and before the .compareTo().

Kindly assist me here, checked docs, other answers, everything i can in last two days....

in simple words i want to know that from where and which values getTitle() gets  to compare.

Comment: *"the thing which cracking me up is from where getTitle() gets the value"* From the instance on which `compareTo` was called, exactly as though it were written `return this.getTitle().compareTo(s.getTitle());` (note the `this.`).

Comment: i got what you said sir, but the thing i am unclear of is from where this.getTitle() gets the value ? i printed the value of this.getTitle(); and it was the title of the second element of songsList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public int compareTo(Song s)` is used to compare 2 `Song` objects. One of them is the one the method is called on, and the other is passed as an argument.

For example :

```
Song s1 = ...
Song s2 = ...
int s1.compareTo(s2);
```

In this example, `getTitle()` in the body of `public int compareTo(Song s)` will return the title of `s1`, while `s.getTitle()` wil return the title of `s2`.

`Collections.sort(songsList);` will always use `compareTo` to compare 2 `Song` objects - one of them it will call the method on, and the other will be passed as an argument.

Comment: ok, so it means in my program... the First element of songsList  acts as arguments and the second element is the one on which the method gets called ?

Comment: @Mr.PooP That depends on the implementation of `Collections.sort()`. `Collections.sort()` performs multiple comparisons, and decides which two `Song`s to compare each time.

Comment: ok, i got what you said and played bit here and there and now have an another noob question... i changed getTitle() to s.getTitle() means compared two same objects... i.e. return s.getTitle().compareTo(s.getTitle()); and it did not sorted the list. ok its because of the same object comparision. so my question is what removing 's' from s.getTitle() makes compareTo() method to provide different objects to compare?

Comment: @Mr.PooP `s.getTitle().compareTo(s.getTitle())` compares the object passed to the method to itself (which makes no sense), instead of comparing it to the current object (the object on which the method was called), which is what `getTitle().compareTo(s.getTitle())` does.

Comment: ThankYou Sir, after hitting my mind with heavy Hammer (Thor's Hammer) Using Your Clean Explanation, i am able to understand behind the scenes of compareTo () without (or may be less) any trouble. :)